# Make defined train/validation/test split in nntool in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to define myself the percentage of the splits for train/validation/test in nntool in matlab. How to do this? Suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Comment: Thanks x) Hope you have advanced on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your ratios redefining divideParam sub-properties (trainRatio, valRatio testRatio). In case your are using the default divideParam split method:

```
>> net.divideParam

ans = 


    Function Parameters for 'dividerand'

    Training Ratio trainRatio: 0.7 % Default
    Validation Ratio valRatio: 0.15 % Default
    Test Ratio      testRatio: 0.15 % Default
```

Redefine:

```
net.divideParam.trainRatio = .4;
net.divideParam.valRatio = .3;
net.divideParam.testRatio = .3;
```

New values:

```
Function Parameters for 'dividerand'

Training Ratio trainRatio: 0.4
Validation Ratio valRatio: 0.3
Test Ratio      testRatio: 0.3
```

You may see the other divide methods and information at topic 2.8 from the matlab documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/nnet/nnet_ug.pdf).