# Correct practice and approach for reporting the training and generalization performance

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, training-data, confusion-matrix

I am trying to learn the correct procedure for training a neural network for classification. Many tutorials are there but they never explain how to report for the generalization performance. Can somebody please tell me if the following is the correct method or not. I am using first 100 examples from the fisheriris data set that has labels 1,2 and call them as `X` and `Y` respectively. Then I split `X` into `trainData` and `Xtest` with a 90/10 split ratio. Using `trainData` I trained the NN model. Now the NN internally further splits `trainData` into tr,val,test subsets. My confusion is which one is usually used for generalization purpose when reporting the performance of the model to unseen data in conferences/Journals?
The dataset can be found in the link: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71468-simple-neural-networks-with-k-fold-cross-validation-manner

```
rng('default')
load iris.mat;

X = [f(1:100,:) l(1:100)];

numExamples = size(X,1);
indx = randperm(numExamples);
X = X(indx,:);
Y = X(:,end);


split1 = cvpartition(Y,'Holdout',0.1,'Stratify',true); %90% trainval 10% test

istrainval = training(split1); % index for fitting
istest = test(split1);      % indices for quality assessment

trainData = X(istrainval,:);

Xtest = X(istest,:);
Ytest = Y(istest);


numExamplesXtrainval = size(trainData,1);

indxXtrainval = randperm(numExamplesXtrainval);
trainData = trainData(indxXtrainval,:);
Ytrain = trainData(:,end);

hiddenLayerSize = 10;

% data format = rows = number of dim, column = number of examples
net  = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);
net  = init(net);
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';
net.trainFcn = 'trainscg';
net.trainParam.epochs=50;

[net tr]= train(net,trainData', Ytrain');
Trained = sim(net, trainData');  %outputs predicted labels

train_predict = net(trainData');

performanceTrain = perform(net,Ytrain',train_predict)
lbl_train=grp2idx(Ytrain);
Yhat_train = (train_predict >= 0.5);
Lbl_Yhat_Train = grp2idx(Yhat_train);   
[cmMatrixTrain]=  confusionmat(lbl_train,Lbl_Yhat_Train )

accTrain=sum(lbl_train ==Lbl_Yhat_Train)/size(lbl_train,1);
disp(['Training Set:    Total Train Acccuracy by MLP = ',num2str(100*accTrain ), '%'])

[confTest] =  confusionmat(lbl_train(tr.testInd),Lbl_Yhat_Train(tr.testInd) )


%unknown test
test_predict = net(Xtest');

performanceTest = perform(net,Ytest',test_predict);
Yhat_test = (test_predict >= 0.5);
test_lbl=grp2idx(Ytest);
Lbl_Yhat_Test = grp2idx(Yhat_test);

[cmMatrix_Test]=  confusionmat(test_lbl,Lbl_Yhat_Test )
```

This is the output.

Problem1: There seems to be no prediction for the other class. Why?

Problem2: Do I need a separate dataset like the one I created as `Xtest` for reporting generalization error or is it the practice to use the data `trainData(tr.testInd,:)` as the generalization test set? Did I create an unnecessary subset?

```
performanceTrain =

   2.2204e-16


cmMatrixTrain =

    45     0
    45     0

Training Set:    Total Train Acccuracy by MLP = 50%

confTest =

     9     0
     5     0


cmMatrix_Test =

     5     0
     5     0
```

Comment: I cannot execute your code because I dont have iris.mat. I also don't understand it, did you not intend to write Y = X(indx,end); ? this may explain why you have missing classes

Comment: @YuvalHarpaz: `X` contains the class labels in the last column. Before taking the classes into the variable `Y` I already changed `X` by `X = X(indx,:)` This reassigns the shuffled array back to the same variable `X`. Therefore, if I do `Y = X(:,end)` it means I am taking the labels from the `X` array that has been now shuffled.

Comment: Can you pleas explain the second point mentioned in Problem2 which is do I need a separate data set for reporting the generalization performance or is the generalization performance reporting using the test subset that is accessible using `tr` which is the training record structure.

Comment: You usually need train and validation subsets to train the network, and keep test data aside for reporting performance. You sometimes can only use train-test data-sets (for a fixed number of training epochs). In your question you refer to train,val,test split but I don't see it in your code. Since I cannot run your code I cannot help you much. If you can, start from load fisheriris, I don't have iris

Comment: @YuvalHarpaz: The dataset can be downloaded from the link: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71468-simple-neural-networks-with-k-fold-cross-validation-manner  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code. Let's deal with them before answering your question. First, you set a threshold of 0.5 for making decisions (`Yhat_train = (train_predict >= 0.5);`) while all points of your net prediction are above 0.5. This means you only get zeros in your confusion matrices. You can plot the scores to choose a better threshold:

```
figure;
plot(train_predict(Ytrain == 1),'.b')
hold on
plot(train_predict(Ytrain == 2),'.r')
legend('label 1','label 2')
```

cvpartition gave me an error. It ran successfully as `split1 = cvpartition(Y,'Holdout',0.1);` In any case, artificial neural networks usuallly manage partitioning within the training process, so you feed in X and Y and some parameters for how to do it. See here for example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624012/make-defined-train-validation-test-split-in-nntool-in-matlab/18624166#18624166) where you set

```
net.divideParam.trainRatio = .4;
net.divideParam.valRatio = .3;
net.divideParam.testRatio = .3;
```

So how to report the results? Only for the test data. The train data will suffer from overfit, and will show false, too good results. If you use validation data (you havn't), then you cannot show results for it because it will also suffer from overfit. If you let the training do validation for you your test results will be safe from overfit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Few things are not clear, can you please clarify?(1)What should be the threshold?(2) You said that the test data should be used to report the performance. This is my confusion since ther are 2 kinds of test data--one that is created by the NN itself using `net.divideParam.testRatio` and the other is the hold out set created by `cvpartition` using the split1 variable. This is the question in Problem2. (3) If I were to use CV for training so once outside the CV loop do I need to call `init()` to create a new NN & re-train the training set used in the CV process?

Comment: The threshold should be between the red and blue points, say 1.9. Finding good thresholds is a science of its own. If you use K-Fold approach for cross-validation then you have to start a new network every iteration. In such a case I would only report the average results for all 10 iterations. You keep 10% of the data for the test, but you do it 10 times and report the average result

Comment: You are saying that the hold out set should be evaluated inside the CV loop, this is not clear?The Matlab code that I linked to shows the CV approach if you may kindly look at the function `jFFF` which creates a feedforward NN. In the code, the CV loop has a `xtrain` and `xtest` and it reports the avg accuracy over the 10 folds. This part is clear to me. The code uses the entire fisheriris dataset and does not create an unseen dataset. My question is that how to report the generalization performance once the CV is over?

Comment: Outside CV do we re-train using the `net` model created inside the CV loop and use `net.tstInd` that can create the test data set OR should there be a holdout set that is created using `cvpartition` before CV loop?

Comment: I would not train the model once inside and once outside CV. How to report is a matter of personal preferences. I usually look at AUC of the ROC curve (should be close to 100%). Sometime I report hit-rate and FA rate. You can also report precision - recall

Comment: Umm, are you sure we don't train inside the CV?

Comment: You train only inside